# JSON data is not returned

Tags: php, json, getjson

The problem is that the alert message "TEST" does not appear, although the function `getData.php` is successfully executed and returns some data. I checked it in Firelog, where I can see the following output:

```
Array{"arr":[["1","EZY14ZM","2013-05-29 16:44:38","2013-05-29 16:45:28"],["1","VLG1307","2013-05-29 16:47:05","2013-05-29 16:47:55"],["1","WZZ212","2013-05-29 16:49:12","2013-05-29 16:50:02"]],"dep":[["1","VLG8306","2013-05-29 16:59:17","2013-05-29 17:00:00"],["1","VLG3786","2013-05-29 17:07:29","2013-05-29 17:08:12"],["1","IBE1851","2013-05-29 17:08:38","2013-05-29 17:09:21"],["1","DLH58Y","2013-05-29 17:09:47","2013-05-29 17:10:30"]]}
```

How to solve this problem?

```
function show_data() {
 $.getJSON(
    'h_index.php?module=mod_1&pag_mod=getData.php',
    function(data) {
       alert("TEST");
    }
 );             
}
```

**getData.php**

```
<?php
   //...
   echo json_encode(array('arr' => $rows_arr, 'dep' => $rows_dep););
   die();
?>
```

Comment: From that Array appearing in the response, I'm guessing you're echoing out an array further up in getData.php

Comment: @Ryan Pilbeam: To check this, I changed json_encode in the following way: json_encode(array('TEST'=>$rows_arr...) As a result I got Array{"TEST":[["1"... So, this echo returns the JSON data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote: your data as viewed in Firebug:

```
Array{"arr":[["1","EZY14ZM","2013-05-29 16:44 .....
```

Note the `Array` at the start of that..... this is not valid JSON.

The actual `json_encode()` function you're calling is fine. It does have an extra stray semi-colon, but that's invalid PHP syntax, so I assume it's crept in when you posted the question rather than being in your actual code.

So the stray text `Array` is not being produced by the `json_encode()` function, so it must be coming from somewhere else in your PHP. Look for an `echo` or a `print` elsewhere in your code that is outputting it by mistake. (probably by printing an array variable rather than the actual string "Array")

Comment: To check this, I changed json_encode in the following way: json_encode(array('TEST'=>$rows_arr...) As a result I got Array{"TEST":[["1"... So, this echo returns the JSON data.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos - Your test doesn't actually prove anything. As I said, the "Array" is coming from somewhere else in your code; it's not coming from the `json_encode()`. You can prove this by commenting out the `json_encode()` line entirely... you will find that you still have the "Array" text in the output.

Comment: yes,that's true. So, do I need to find and comment some echo?

Comment: Yes. Exactly as I said in the answer, you need to find the echo or print somewhere else in your code that is doing this and remove it. I don't know where else in your code it is, as you haven't shown us any more of it, but it's there somewhere. You'll have to find id.